# How can I retrieve the point coordinates from a LOG Plot after the data points were manually moved?

Tags: plotting, expression-manipulation

I'm having problems with getting coordinates out ofa `ListLogLogPlot`

I basically plotted a list, then selected data points on the graph, moved these points around, and now I need to get the coordinates of the moved points.

Any ideas?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fhai.png]
[image]

Comment: Something like : `Cases[ListPlot[{{0, Pi}, {1, E}}], Point[pts__] :> pts, Infinity] ` ?

Comment: please see screenshot I added

Comment: You can do `newPlot= copy/paste here` and then the above on `newPlot`.

Comment: this is the thing I was looking for ;] But it works weird; namely, when I take Cases[newPlot, Point[pts__] :> pts, Infinity] it gives points as if they were on linear scale, not log... have a look at second screenshot I've added...

Comment: @Luke, you'll need to do `Cases[(paste plot here), Point[pts__] :> Exp[pts], -1]`.

Comment: @SimonWoods it works!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one works for both Log and LogLog Plots. Create your plot:

```
ListLogLogPlot[Table[{n, n}, {n, 50}]]
```

Edit it. Then paste it here

```
ListLogLogPlot@ Cases[#, (Point[x__] :> ("CopiedValueFunction" /. (CoordinatesToolOptions /. 
                      Options[#, CoordinatesToolOptions])) /@ x), Infinity] &@ (---Paste HERE ---)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works great, however `Cases[(paste plot here), Point[pts__] :> Exp[pts], -1]` works as well, thanks anyway

Comment: @Luke The difference is that this one works for both Log and LogLog Plots :)

Comment: +1 [Grrrrrrrreat](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzuzraGpvX1r4w0l4.jpg)

Comment: @Rojo Thanks :). I think there is a cleaner way to get sub-options. Anyway ...

Comment: Well, it's a matter of taste, but you could do `OptionValue[Options@gr, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> "CopiedValueFunction"]`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is as follows. Take your new plot as it is in the notebook after you introduced the changes, mark it by clicking and copy it. Then type FullForm[] in a new cell and insert the copied graphics between the square brackets. Evaluate it. The result will be rather lengthily. However you will be able to find there a Line statement somewhere inside this lengthily expression. The Line statement is wrapped around a list. Copy this list. Done.